# Getting the rect of the rotated view in willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Tags: uiviewcontroller, core-animation, ios, autorotate

I am trying to animate between portrait and landscape orientations by hooking the various autorotation methods in `UIViewController`.  Due to some subtleties of my view hierarchy, I'd like to set the frame of a child `UIScrollView` in the first half the animation and then scroll into position during the second half.  This requires knowledge of the final, rotated frame of my view from within `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

The system must know this frame in order to perform the rotation animation, but is it accessible to `UIViewController` subclasses?  If not, are my only options to hardcode the rotated frame or perform all layout in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation...`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to overlook the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` callback.  This resolved my issue, revealing a handful more.  I will leave the question open in case someone else would like to elaborate on two-part rotation animation.  EDIT: Closing, since no takers for days.